# Why is it printing a wrong answer?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

double** findminor(double** a, int n, int flag) {
    double** minor = malloc((n - 1) * sizeof(double*));
    int r = 1, c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++) {
        *(minor + i) = malloc((n - 1) * sizeof(double*));

        for (int j = 0; j < (n - 1); j++) {
            if (c != flag) {
                *(*(minor +i ) + j) = *(*(a + r) + c);
            }
            else {
                c++;
                *(*(minor+i)+j)=*(*(a+r)+c);
            }

            c++;
        }

        r++;
    }

    return minor;
}

void freeMinor(double** minor, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++) {
        free(*(minor + i));
    }

    free(minor);
}

double compute_det(double** a, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return (double)**a;
    }
    
    double result = 0.0;
    double sign = 1.0;
    double** minor = malloc(n * sizeof(double*));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        minor = findminor(a, n, i);
        result += sign * *(*(a) + i) * compute_det(minor, n - 1 - i);
        sign = -1.0;
        freeMinor(minor, n);
    }
  
    return abs(result);
}

void freeMatrix(double** a, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(*(a + i));
    }
    
    free(a);
}

int main(void) {
    int n;
    printf("Input dimensions: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    double** a = malloc(n * sizeof(double*));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        *(a + i) = malloc(n * sizeof(double));

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%lf ", (*(a + i) + j));
        }
    }
    
    printf("%.lf\n", compute_det(a, n));
    freeMatrix(a, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Hey, so I'm trying to code a program that computes a determinant for any size.
I'm not sure where I'm going wrong because when I pass in these values, which are in a .in file I'm getting 15 instead of 105

```
4
1 2 3 4
5 2 3 1
2 5 0 1
3 2 4 2
```

However, I'm also getting a memory leak. Is this what makes my code face errors?

```
==28233== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==28233== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==28233== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28233== Command: ./det
==28233== 
==28233== Invalid read of size 8
==28233==    at 0x10929B: findminor (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1093FE: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1095E3: main (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==  Address 0x4a4c800 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==28233==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28233==    by 0x109572: main (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233== 
==28233== Invalid read of size 8
==28233==    at 0x10929B: findminor (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1093FE: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x10943D: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1095E3: main (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==  Address 0x4a4ca38 is 0 bytes after a block of size 24 alloc'd
==28233==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28233==    by 0x10923B: findminor (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1093FE: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1095E3: main (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233== 
==28233== Invalid read of size 8
==28233==    at 0x1092F1: findminor (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1093FE: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x10943D: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1095E3: main (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==  Address 0x4a4ca38 is 0 bytes after a block of size 24 alloc'd
==28233==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28233==    by 0x10923B: findminor (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1093FE: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1095E3: main (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233== 
==28233== Invalid read of size 8
==28233==    at 0x1092F1: findminor (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1093FE: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1095E3: main (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==  Address 0x4a4c800 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==28233==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28233==    by 0x109572: main (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233== 
Input dimensions: 15
==28233== 
==28233== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28233==     in use at exit: 88 bytes in 8 blocks
==28233==   total heap usage: 48 allocs, 40 frees, 2,376 bytes allocated
==28233== 
==28233== 0 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 4
==28233==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28233==    by 0x1093DA: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x10943D: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x10943D: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x10943D: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1095E3: main (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233== 
==28233== 16 bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 4
==28233==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28233==    by 0x1093DA: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x10943D: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x10943D: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1095E3: main (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233== 
==28233== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 4
==28233==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28233==    by 0x1093DA: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1095E3: main (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233== 
==28233== 40 bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
==28233==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28233==    by 0x1093DA: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x10943D: compute_det (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233==    by 0x1095E3: main (in /home/u6480784/a3/det/det)
==28233== 
==28233== LEAK SUMMARY:
==28233==    definitely lost: 88 bytes in 8 blocks
==28233==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28233==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28233==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28233==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28233== 
==28233== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==28233== ERROR SUMMARY: 34 errors from 8 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Is there anything I could do?

Comment: For any pointer (or array) `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The latter is much easier to read, write and undesrstand.

Comment: And `a[r][c]` is even more easy to read than `*(*(a+r)+c)`.

Comment: Also build with debug info (add `-g` when building) and Valgrind will be able to report exact line numbers where it detects problems. Use it for further debugging sessions, where you for example check all indexes you use, and make sure they are in range.

Comment: Also, you have `double **minor = malloc(...);` followed by `minor = findminor(...);`.  What happens with the pointer returned by that initial call to `malloc`?

Comment: This is often wrong: `scanf("%lf ", (*(a+i)+j));` please remove the trailing space so `scanf("%lf", (*(a+i)+j));`

Comment: The cast in `return (double) **a;` is superfluous; it might be better to write `return a[0][0];` to indicate the value returned is the zero/zero element of the matrix.

Comment: `return abs(result);` is wrong: `return fabs(result);`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yeah, that was useless. I just fixed it. No leaks are possible. However, I'm still not getting the expected answer for some reason. I tried to trace it on paper, and it seems fitting to me for some reason. Is there something wrong with the way I'm adding? Kind of unsure about that. But I can't think of a solution. I even tried removing i, but I'm only getting 0.

Comment: Should `sign = -1.0;` be `sign *= -1.0;` although the ouput is stil `15`?

Comment: Even for a pointer, `a[r][c]` is perfectly valid. Teachers that require explicit pointer-arithmetic syntax should have a stern talking to.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah just tried that after compiling it. Still getting the same output. However, it was a required change.

Answer (score 1):

To get this working, I've changed the unreadable pointer notation to array notation, you can change it back. I've also made the assumption that a matrix is always at least 2x2 and set that as the recursion limit.

The code now outputs `-105.000000` for the given input.

Some errors in `findminor()` were:

- Allocation of `sizeof(double*)` in the loop. This will cause a fault with 32-bit pointers
- The `int c=0` should be inside the loop, was initialised once only
- The loop control is off-by-one
- You copy the array element whether or not it's the 'skipped' column
- The wrong variable is used to index
- `c` is incremented once or *twice*

Some changes in `compute_det()` were:

- Fault with `sign = -1.0` which should be `sign *= -1.0`
- Remove memory leak of `double** minor = malloc(n*sizeof(double*));` outside the loop
- Incorrect matrix size passed to recursion
- Removed the `abs` from `return abs(result)`, even `return fabs(result)` gives the wrong answer

Finally in `main()` removed the trailing space in `scanf`. Please see [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

double** findminor(double** a, int n, int flag){
    double** minor = malloc((n-1)*sizeof(double*));
    int r = 1;
    for (int i=0;i<(n-1);i++){
        int c = 0;      // error here c reset outside of loop
        minor[i] = malloc((n-1)*sizeof(double));  // error *double
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(j != flag){
                minor[i][c] = a[r][j];
                c++;
            }
        }
        r++;
    }
    return minor;
}

void freeMinor(double** minor, int n){
    for(int i=0;i<(n-1) ;i++){
        free(minor[i]);
    }
    free(minor);
}


double compute_det(double** a, int n) {
    if(n == 2)
        return a[0][0] * a[1][1] - a[1][0] * a[0][1];

    double result = 0.0;
    double sign = 1.0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        double** minor = findminor(a, n, i);
        result += sign * a[0][i] * compute_det(minor, n-1); //here
        sign *= -1.0;
        freeMinor(minor, n);
    }
    return result;
}

void freeMatrix(double** a, int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        free(a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
}

int main(void) {
    int n;
    printf("Input dimensions: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    double** a = malloc(n*sizeof(double*));
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        a[i]=malloc(n*sizeof(double));
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
            scanf("%lf", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("%lf\n", compute_det(a, n));
    freeMatrix(a, n);
    return 0;
}
```